# Prove that the set of all polynomials with real coefficients is infinite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra

That is: Let $n ≥ 0$ be an integer. Prove that $P(R)$ is not $n$-dimensional.

I'm thinking a proof by contradiction.

Comment: It follows from the infinitude of degrees a polynomial can assume: $x^{10}$, $x^{100}$, $x^{1000}$, etc. - and then showing their independence.

Comment: You may prove that $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots,x^N$ are linearly independent by computing a (non-zero) determinant of a Vandermonde matrix, for instance. That proves the dimension of such a space is not bounded by any $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Or: assuming that $1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^N$ are linearly dependent, there is some non-zero polynomial that vanishes at every integer. But the number of real roots of a polynomial is bounded by its degree, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a lemma:

> Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ and define $$P_S=\bigcup_{n\in S} \{x^n\}\subset P(\mathbb R).$$ Then $P_S$ is linearly independent.

Suppose $c(x)=\sum_{n\in S}c_nx^n=0$ where each $c_n\in\mathbb R$. Let $C = \{n\in S:c_n\ne 0\}$. Then $|C|\ne 1$, as otherwise $c(1)=c_j$ for the lone $j\in C$. If $|C|\geqslant 2$, then for each $j\in C$, let $x_j$ be a nonzero root of $c(x)-c_jx^j$. Then $c(x_j) = c_jx_j^j\ne0 $. (If there is no nonzero root, then $0\in C$ and hence $c(0) = c_0\ne 0$). This is a contradiction, and so we conclude that $|C|=0$.

Now, suppose $\dim P(\mathbb R) = n$. Then there exists a basis $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ for $P(\mathbb R)$. Let $$D = \max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}\deg p_i,$$ then we conclude that $\deg p\leqslant D$ for all $p\in P(\mathbb R)$. But $x^{D+1}\in P(\mathbb R)$, hence contradiction.

Comment: @Thomas True, I did assume that in my proof. I will revise it.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that, by definition, $\mathbf R[X]$, as an $\mathbf R$-vector space is $\mathbf R^{(\mathbf N)}$, i.e. the set of all infinite sequences of real numbers that are eventually $0$.

For  a non-zero sequence $p=(a_0, a_1,\dots, a_k,\dots)$, the greatest $k$ such that $a_k\ne 0$ is the *degree* of the polynomial $p$. We set $\deg 0=-\infty$.

The degree has the following  properties:

1. $\deg(pq)=\deg  p+\deg q$,
2. $\deg(p+q)\le \max(\deg p, \deg q).$

It follows that a polynomial in the subspace generated by a finite set of polynomials $p_1, \dots, p_n$ has degree *at most* $\max(\deg p_1,\dots, \deg p_n)$.

However, there are polynomials of arbitrary degree. Thus a finite set of polynomials cannot generate the whole space of polynomials.